# Scraping data from individual results in a list of providers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get addresses of all the therapists by given zip code. I want to input a zip code and get a list of result. Then, go into individual result and scrape the address of the provider.

I'm new to python. I've been trying to use requests and BeautifulSoup. Maybe using Selenium might be better?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/60148'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(page.content.decode())
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

myclass = soup.find_all(class_='result-row normal-result row')
print(myclass)
```

I'm stuck now. Not sure how to proceed.
PS. I am taking a python course as we speak. Please be kind.

Comment: What's the problem/question you have?

Comment: @Nordle how can I get the data from individual search result page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this, you will get addresses of all the therapists by given zip code:**

But this provides only 1-page number address list if you want to get all pages of the address then you should use selenium, will resolve your problem.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

url = 'https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/60148'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find(class_='results-column')

addressArray = []

for tag in result:

    if isinstance(tag,Tag):
        _class = tag.get("class")

        if _class is None or _class is not None and "row" not in _class:
            continue

        link = (tag.find(class_='result-actions')).find('a',href=True)
        
        _href = link['href']

        address_link = requests.get(_href, headers=headers)
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(address_link.text, 'html.parser')

        address = (soup1.find(class_='address')).find(class_="location-address-phone")

        text = ''
        for index,data in enumerate((address.text.strip()).split('\n')):
            if not data.strip():
                continue

            if not text:
                text = data.strip()
            else:
                text = text+","+data.strip()

        if text:
            addressArray.append(text)

print(addressArray)
```

O/P:

```
['Lia Reynolds, LCSW,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 343-5819', 'Clarity Counseling and Wellness, LLC,477 Butterfield Road,#202,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 656-9713', '450 East 22nd St.,Suite 172,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(773) 599-3959', '10 E 22nd Street,Suite 217,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 517-9505', 'Ron Ahlberg & Associates,477 E Butterfield Rd,Suite 310,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 451-8653', 'Health Transitions Counseling,477 Butterfield Road,Suite 310,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 785-6642', 'Way Beyond Counseling and Coaching,477 E Butterfield Road,Floor 3 - Wellness Center - Office 7,Lombard, Illinois 60148,Call Mr. Larry Westenberg,(630) 556-8484', 'Chicago Area Behavioral Health Services,150 W St Charles Road,Lombard, Illinois 60148,Call Augustus Edeh. Chicago Area Behavioral Health Services,(630) 599-8032', 'Adult Children Center, Ltd,2 East 22nd Street,Suite 302,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 387-9750', 'Midwest Center for Hope & Healing, Ltd.,1165 S Westmore-meyers Rd,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 765-5355', 'Madrigal Consulting and Counseling, LLP,450 E. 22nd Street,Suite 150,Lombard, Illinois 60148,Call Cesar Madrigal,(630) 413-9942', '477 E Butterfield Rd,Suite 202,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 560-6920', 'Lombard,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 796-7904', 'Dupage Clinical Counseling Services,450 E 22nd St,150,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 313-4990', '2200 S Main St,Suite 316,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 426-7819', 'Institute for Motivational Development,10 E 22nd Street, Suite 217,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(309) 723-8170', 'Michele DeCanio Counseling Services,2200 S. Main Street,Suite 305,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 560-6926', 'A New Day Counseling Center,450 E 22nd St,Suite 150,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 748-8261', '477 E Butterfield Rd,Suite 310,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 426-6878', 'Bricolage Wellness,477 Butterfield Road,Suite 202,Lombard, Illinois 60148,(630) 426-7823']
```

where `'result-actions'` is action view button class to open new page, so it's required to make one more request to get full address.

`"location-address-phone"` is new address page class to **scrape** address.

**Documentation link:**

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Wow this is great. Thank you so much.
just one issue. What variable are you using for output?

Comment: I see it now. That was extremely helpful. I'm new to Python. I wish to be as good as you one day. 
A follow-up, if you have time: how can I have it scrape multiple pages as the results are divided into multiple pages.

Comment: @DrFahizzle you need to learn how to use selenium with beautiful soup.